# Mailx is not sending email notification in CentOS

Tags: centos, mailx

I am creating script which would send out a notification through mailx when a condition is met.

mail -s "PROCESS is down!" XXXX@mydomain.com

I don't see a email getting sent or I don't know where to look to troubleshoot.

Could someone throw light on this.

Regards,
Ranjith

Comment: maybe [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-send-e-mail-alerts-on-a-centos-vps-for-system-monitoring) help

Comment: Thank you.. got it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Established that mailx in correctly installed  with "yum install mailx" you can try the following I successfully tested on Cetos 7.6

```
echo "TEST" | mailx -v -r "yoursender@xxx.yy" -s "TEST" \
-S smtp="smt.yourserver.com" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp-auth-user="username \
-S smtp-auth-password="password" \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
-S nss-config-dir="/etc/pki/nssdb/" your.recipient@xxx.yy
```